# Dictionary in swift acts unpredictable

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I have set of parameters of in a dictionary parameters:[String: Any]. 
Moreover I have a few of this kind of parameters, and my app is required to store them and toggling each on button press.

code :

```
var filterParameters: [String: Any] = [:]
var countryFilterParameters: [String: Any] = [:]

@IBAction func segmentHasChanged(_ sender: Any) {
    if let segment = sender as? UISegmentedControl {
        let currentCountryCode = ApiManager.shared.mainCountryCode
        switch segment.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            let filterParametersCopy = self.filterParameters
            self.countryFilterParameters[currentCountryCode] = filterParametersCopy
            ApiManager.shared.setCountryCode(_countryCode: "kz")
            if let uwCountryFilterParameters = self.countryFilterParameters["kz"] as? [String : Any] {
                self.filterParameters = uwCountryFilterParameters
            } else {
                self.filterParameters.removeAll()
            }
            break
        case 1:
            let filterParametersCopy = self.filterParameters
            self.countryFilterParameters[currentCountryCode] = filterParametersCopy
            ApiManager.shared.setCountryCode(_countryCode: "ru")
            if let uwCountryFilterParameters = self.countryFilterParameters["ru"] as? [String : Any] {
                self.filterParameters = uwCountryFilterParameters
            } else {
                self.filterParameters.removeAll()
            }
            break
        case 2:
            let filterParametersCopy = self.filterParameters
            self.countryFilterParameters[currentCountryCode] = filterParametersCopy
            ApiManager.shared.setCountryCode(_countryCode: "by")
            if let uwCountryFilterParameters = self.countryFilterParameters["by"] as? [String : Any] {
                self.filterParameters = uwCountryFilterParameters
            } else {
                self.filterParameters.removeAll()
            }
            break
        default:
            break
        }
        self.loadTenders()
    }
}
```

expected dictionary :

```
["kz": ["q": "some key word", "start_date": ""],
 "ru": ["q": "other key word", "start_date": ""]]
```

but everytime I try to access countryFilterParameters it erases old values. i.e.: when I do countryFilterParameters["by"] = ["q": "another key word", "start_date": ""].
debugPrint(CountryFilterParameters) prints ["by": ["q": "another key word", "start_date": ""]]

the problem is each time new key value added to global dictionary it erases old one. What could be the problem and how is it possible to solve it?

I've read that dictionary is a struct, so it is a value type. so I am confused, what is done wrong?

Comment: This code block resets the dictionaries to empty values every time it runs. Separate the declaration elsewhere if you don't want this to happen.

Comment: @Desdenova my bad, the declaration happens outside of the method. check edited code

Comment: I'm not sure why you remove all elements in `filterParameters` or reassign it by `filterParameters = uwCountryFilterParameters`, and then you want to keep its old key-value pairs?

Comment: It is really unclear what you are trying to achieve here. Maybe you could give examples of the expected before and after states of each dictionary? Also it might be clearer if you defined the value type for each dictionary too.

Comment: @TristanBurnside please check the edited question

Comment: @Lawliet I am trying to save them in countryFilterParameters, while for each segment I want different filterParameters to be active

Comment: What is `ApiManager.shared.mainCountryCode`? Is `ApiManager.shared.setCountryCode(_countryCode: "kz")` to set the `mainCountryCode` to be "kz"?

Comment: @Lawliet yes, now in logs I have this weird behavior ["kz": [:], "by": [:], "ru": ["finish_date": "", "summa_from": "", "bin": "", "itogi": false, "not_show_finished": false, "q": "Cobb", "start_date": "", "summa_to": ""]] 
              and when updated   it is ["kz": ["finish_date": "", "summa_from": "", "bin": "", "itogi": false, "not_show_finished": false, "q": "qwer", "start_date": "", "summa_to": ""], "by": [:], "ru": [:]]

Comment: You have a lot of code repetition here. You should limit the `switch` to only handling the differing parts, and then have a shared code path to handle the common parts.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the else part where you remove all values of the dictionary from the code.

```
        else {
                self.filterParameters.removeAll()
            }
```

Remove this statement from both the cases.

Comment: I did try, but filterParameters remain the same for all of the cases. so basically I need to redefine the problem. Which is why all dictionaries are copied with reference type?

Comment: Can you please print the filterParameters and put here ?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you set the `mainCountryCode` by `ApiManager.shared.setCountryCode(_countryCode: "kz")` before getting its value? I'm still not certain of your implementation. The following code is just a hint.

```
var filterParameters: [String: Any] = [:]
var countryFilterParameters: [String: Any] = [:]

@IBAction func segmentHasChanged(_ sender: Any) {
    if let segment = sender as? UISegmentedControl {
        switch segment.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            ApiManager.shared.setCountryCode(_countryCode: "kz")
            break
        case 1:
            ApiManager.shared.setCountryCode(_countryCode: "ru")
            break
        case 2:
            ApiManager.shared.setCountryCode(_countryCode: "by")
            break
        default:
            break
        }

        let currentCountryCode = ApiManager.shared.mainCountryCode
        self.countryFilterParameters[currentCountryCode] = ["q": "other key word", "start_date": ""]
        self.loadTenders()
    }
}
```

Comment: This sounds like the right path to go down, as you are already storing the current country code, you can use and set the parameters for that directly and avoid having a `filterParameters` altogether, it would just become `countryFilterParameters[currentCountryCode]`

Comment: The problem I am trying to solve is to save the current filterParameters before changing the countryCode in ApiManager. So i want to store it like countryFilterParameters[currentCode] = currentFilterParameters. and then change the country code and clean up currentFilterParameters for new parameters

Comment: If you want to save the `countryFilterParameters[currentCode]` before the `currentCountryCode` gets changed, you can move this part up above the `switch`. Why didn't you save the data directly to `countryFilterParameters[currentCode]`? I still don't know what is the role of `filterParameters` based on your code.